# Accessing properties based on context of WAR (Multiple WARs in single EAR)

Tags: java, war, ear, websphere-7

I'm having an EAR generated with two WAR files, with a unique context name provided for each war.

After deploying the EAR in Websphere Application Server 7, I find that, whichever context is hit first gets loaded properly, while the second context hit, loads the same page as that of the first context.

On further analysis, we found that there is a properties file with the same name available separately for WAR 1 and WAR 2. Ideally what is happening is, the properties file of the first context that is being accessed is getting loaded and the properties values are stored in cache.

Hence when the second context is hit, the same static properties loaded are being referred resulting in the same first context page getting loaded.

The problem here is the properties name are common for both the WARS while the value holds the context name statically for each WAR.

How can I make the context name to be dynamically identified and the corresponding properties referred ??

Waiting for directions..

Thank you !

My problem now is that I have a set of properties with same name but different values based on the context, for instance a property named "redirectURL" with value as "context1/page1" or "context2/page2". So long since the wars were separately deployed on tomcat, each war had these properties loaded through different properties file and worked fine. Now on migrating to WAS, i had to club them in a single EAR and that is when only one of the properties file gets loaded and the values cached and reused for other context also. Please suggest on resolving this. Thank you !

Comment: What is the path of the properties file? What code do you suspect is loading it (WebSphere or the app)? In what data structure is it being cached? Do you believe this is a WebSphere issue, or just an issue that is occurring while using WebSphere (i.e., do you know the app works on another app server)?

Comment: Hi bkail, To answer your questions a) The path of the properties file is currently within the Web-app project's Java source package named properties b) This issue is not related to Websphere, because the properties file is being read and loaded by the App code only c) The properties are static, they contain the context name in the value of the property attributes and they are stored as key value pairs in Map.

Comment: Is the class with the static loaded by the EAR class loader rather than the WAR class loader?  What does System.out.println(ClassWithProps.class.getClassLoader()) say?  If it's an "app:whatever" class loader rather than a "war:whatever" class loader, then try moving the JAR with the classes into WEB-INF/lib/.